# Issue Uploading multiple image from Gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery

I can't upload multiple images. I get the image path successfully from galley. but i can't get image successfully in android studio

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
      images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_SELECTED_IMAGES);
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for (int i = 0, l = images.size(); i < l; i++) {
        sb.append(images.get(i).getPath() + "\n");
        //  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(images);
      }
      tvtest.setText(sb.toString());
      encodedimage=sb.toString();
   }
}
```

Comment: upload image where?

Comment: how to get image from gallery

Comment: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-pick-image-from-gallery/

Comment: I dont get image from gallery in samsung J5 using this code.

Comment: data field must be coming null. google for samsung. tons of articles on SO as well